# How to search for a strings in a row and create an array with them VBA

Tags: string, vba, excel, find

I need a macro to look for a string (that string comes from an array) in a row and then after locating that cell in which the string is, store the value next to it into another array. Is there a way of doing this or am I thinking of something impossible? This is what I got so far

```
Sub ListWorkSheetNames()
Dim Cellnames(1000) As String
Dim Shrinkage(1000) As Double
For i = 1 To Application.Sheets.Count 
Cellnames(i) = Application.Sheets(i).Name   

strName = Cellnames(i)

Shrinkage(i) = Workbooks(strProjectedRevenue).Worksheet("Month").Rows(2).Find(What:=strName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

Workbooks(strB.xlsm).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & i) = Shrinkage
Workbooks(strB.xlsm).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i) = strName

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean the string is comes from an arrow in a row? Do you mean that the cells contain arrays?? Or that the values in the cells came from an VBA array before?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two arrays from what I can see.

Is this what you are trying (**UNTESTED**)? I have commented the code. Do let me know if you have a question.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsI As Worksheet
    Dim MyAr As Variant
    Dim SearchString As String, tmpString As String, sDelim As String
    Dim aCell As Range

    '~~> Worksheet where you need to search
    Set wsI = Workbooks(strProjectedRevenue).Worksheet("Month")

    '~~> I am assuming that none of the sheets have this name. Else Change it
    '~~> to something unique
    sDelim = "lbochitt"

    '~~> Loop through the worksheets
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        '~~> Search String
        SearchString = ws.Name

        '~~> Find the string
        Set aCell = wsI.Rows(2).Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        '~~> Check if the result returned anything
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            '~~> Store the offset value in a string separated with a delimiter
            If tmpString = "" Then
                tmpString = aCell.Offset(, 1).Value
            Else
                tmpString = tmpString & sDelim & aCell.Offset(, 1).Value
            End If
            Set aCell = Nothing
        Next
    Next

    If tmpString <> "" Then
        '~~> here is your final array
        MyAr = Split(tmpString, sDelim)
    End If
End Sub
```